# A basic question on denseness in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a metric space with a countable dense subset. Now consider a subset $E$ and a $p \in E$. Now consider the set $\cup_{q \in E, q \neq p}N_{r_i}(q)$. Does it set covers $p$, $\forall r_i >0$. It looks like so. How to prove it ?

The notation $r_i$ means that radius of a neighbourhood of $q$ depends on the point $q$. For example, in $\Bbb R$ suppose we have a neighbourhood $N_r(p)$ of a point $p$. Then if I choose any neighbourhood for each $q \in N_r(p), q \neq p$ and take the union of this neighbourhoods. Does this set covers $p$ ? If true, is it true for any metric space with countable dense subset in general ? Does it make sense now ?

Comment: It isn’t clear what you’re asking. First, your use of the subscript $i$ makes no sense: if $i$ is a constant, you just don’t need it, and if it depends on $q$, you should say so. I’m going to assume that you mean $r_q$, a radius that depends on $q$. If there is some $q\in E\setminus\{p\}$ for which $r_q>d(q,p)$, then of course $p\in N_{r_q}(q)$, which is a subset of your union. On the other hand, if $r_q\le d(p,q)$ for each $q\in E\setminus\{p\}$, then your union does not contain $p$.

Comment: Is it your question: "Suppose we have a metric space, with a countable dense subset $Q$. Now consider the set $$\bigcup_{\substack{ q \in Q\cap (E\setminus\{p\})\\ r\gt 0}}N_r(q).$$ Does it covers $p$?" ?

Comment: Are you too busy asking such a lot of questions, that you can't reply to the comments people leaves asking for clarification? It is good to ask questions, it's very important actually, but you'll get more chances to get them answered if you are more responsive.

Comment: @leo: sorry, I clarified the problem definition now.

Comment: @leo: I am asking even whether the set $\cup_{E-\{p\}}N_r(q)$ covers $p$. Here $r$ depends on the point $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that for each $q\in E\setminus\{p\}$ we’ve chosen a radius $r(q)>0$. Whether or not $p\in\bigcup_{q\in E\setminus\{p\}}N_{r(q)}(q)$ depends entirely on the choice of radii $r(q)$.

- If $r(q)\le d(p,q)$ for each $q\in E\setminus\{p\}$, then for each $q\in E\setminus\{p\}$ we have $p\notin N_{r(q)}(q)$, so of course $$p\notin\bigcup_{q\in E\setminus\{p\}}N_{r(q)}(q)\;.$$
- If there is a $q_0\in E\setminus\{p\}$ such that $r(q_0)>d(p,q_0)$, then $p\in N_{r(q_0)}(q_0)$, so $$p\in\bigcup_{q\in E\setminus\{p\}}N_{r(q)}(q)\;.$$

Comment: yes, I understood now.

Comment: @Prasenjit: Excellent.